# when i run my code, why does the ellipse/circle not show up

Tags: python, processing

```
from math import sin
from processing import *

X = 30
Y = 30
delay = 16
radius = 30

def setup():
    strokeWeight(10)
    frameRate(20)
    size(500,500)

def sircle():
    global X, Y, radius
    background(100)
    fill(0,121,184)
    stroke(255)
    fc = environment.frameCount

    X += (mouse.x-X)/delay;
    Y += (mouse.y-Y)/delay;

    radius = radius + sin(fc / 4)

draw = sircle
run()
```

for some reason `run()` only creates the background.
does anybody know how to call the function for `sircle()`?

Comment: did you forget a parenthesis draw = sircle() ?

Comment: The only function that's actually _called_ in this code is `run()`, and we have no idea what that does...

Comment: Where in this code are you expecting an ellipse/circle to be drawn?  I see variables that are presumably intended as the center point and radius of a circle, but you never actually do anything with them.

Comment: it's supposed to start where the mouse is and the circle is supposed follow the mouse where ever it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the OP is referring [this code](https://sites.google.com/a/trinket.io/hour-of-python/going-deeper-with-turtle/processing)

where it does seem correct that `draw` is being assigned the function variable `sircle`. Besides, its not like `sircle()` is returning anything that can be assigned to `draw`

Looking at the example code in the link I shared above, you need a line like

```py
ellipse(X,Y,radius,radius)
```

at the end of your `sircle` function

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `sircle()` and `setup()` with parentheses.

These are functions not variables, they demand their parentheses. In your code `draw` variable stores the memory address of `sircle()` function.

Comment: it just gives me a TypeError when i do that